# Why is Yahoo! telling me to pay $100 to unlock my hacked email account?

Tags: account-management, yahoo-mail, yahoo-account

I got locked out of my email after someone in Houston, Texas hacked into it.  I called a number for Yahoo! that no one else can seem to find and they told me that I had to pay $100 because my Yahoo! server had been compromised. I use my cell phone for my email and I am fairly confident that I am not responsible for Yahoo!'s email server. Any ideas on what I can do, because I am getting nowhere with Yahoo!?

Comment: Sounds like a scam to me.

Comment: You can earn the peer-pressure-badge by now.

Answer (score 5):

Yahoo is not trying to charge you $100 to recover your account. That's a scammer, possibly the person(s) who hacked your account in the first place.

To recover your Yahoo account, click the link at the [Yahoo login page](https://login.yahoo.com) that says "[Can't access your account?](https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot?done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&src=ym&partner=reg)". Then follow the instructions.